# vim "set wildmode=list:longest" issue when there's too many matches

Tags: vim

I have many files with same prefix in my working directory, say "sample_000.txt" ... "sample_999.txt".

When I `set wildmode=list:longest` and try to open a file by typing `:e sa<Tab>`, vim lists all matches but my screen is unable to print them all, which leads to a `-- More --` in the last line.

It's annoying that I can't type in any letters when a `-- More --` appears and I have to type a `q` to escape from this and sadly find the command now is still `:e sa`(which is now expected to be the longest common string, i.e. `:e sample_`).

Is this a bug or is there an option to get things right?

Comment: I don't know of a way around the `-- More --`, but if I repeat your steps above, after the `q`, I end up with the longest unambiguous match: `:e sample_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *more prompt* can be globally disabled with `:set nomore`, but I don't think you'll want that. This is hopefully a corner case, and having to press `q` isn't so bad, is it? Alternatively, you can try other `'wildmode'` settings; I like `longest:full,full`.

Like Jim Steward, my Vim (7.3.823) correctly inserts the longest match, so updating to a newer version might help in that regard.